# I have a wordpress site and I would like to use parcel to compile and bundle my sass and js is this possible?

Tags: php, wordpress, sass, stylus, parceljs

My Problem is that when loading styles and js it is all traditionally done by using the add_action('wp_head') I would like to have parceljs simply watch my js and sass files and compile it to one or multiple files depending on whether they are a partial or not. I normally would use gulp but I was hoping it would be easier with a tool that's less dated.

I haven't tried anything yet because it seems that there always needs to be a entry point that's a .html file